# How to reuse a SAS Samsung 1.92TB SSD after NIST800-88?

Tags: ssd, format, sas

I bought a SAS (serial SCSI, not serial SATA) SSD from [this eBay listing](https://www.ebay.com/itm/195659854329) titled: "EMC MZILS1T9HCHP-000C3 1.92TB PM1633 SAS 12GBPS 2.5" SSD, Erased with NIST800-88".

I have read that NIST800-88 is just a means to render data inaccessible.

It could be self-encrypting-based, but the Samsung MZILS1T9HCHP-000C3 doesn't seem to be self-encrypting.

But I can only see the drive under Windows 11 with a SAS to USB to SATA converter, or with an LSI HBA card under Windows Server 2019 with SATA connectors.

I can see that it says that it it 1752GB in size and that it is an Unknown disk, not initialized, unallocated, but I cannot read, write, partition or format it, as if it was encrypted in hardware, but I don't know how to activate it whether it's encrypted or just disabled in some way.

What tools, Linux commands, etc., do I need for being able to reuse it after the NIST800-88 procedure?

Comment: A disk's prior encryption should not impact your use of it now. What OS are you using? Have you initialized the disk?

Comment: Windows 11 and Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Edition. When I try to clean or initialize, it says "DiskPart has referenced an object which is not up-to-date." or input/output error as if it was encrypted or damaged.

Comment: “What tools, Linux commands, etc., do I need for being able to reuse it after the NIST800-88 procedure?” It is just a method used to erase the disk. Just install it and mount it and erase it. Maybe you have to write a new partition, but all NIST800-88 is is a standard for erasing. Now you can do whatever the heck you want with it.

Comment: I have tried everything for reading or writing. Linux just reports an I/O error and all OSes take a very long time to respond. I probably need a SAS-3 HBA card. If that doesn't work, the disk is probably broken or needs something special.

Comment: “I have read that NIST800-88 is just a means to render data inaccessible.” It just means the drive was wiped. Have you attempted to contact the original seller and ask them about this? They would seem to be the authority on how to properly format and use the drive. But if the interface you are using is the issue, then _maybe_ a SAS-3 HBA card is what you need. And that is outside the scope of formatting since the connection and protocol might be the issue. Maybe you should boot into a Linux live CD and attempt to format, partition and erase it from there?

Comment: depending on your linux, `fdisk` or gparted are good places to start. note that "SAS to USB to SATA converter" is just plain a bad idea. if you don't have SAS device support, buy an expansion card that does. this isn't a printer, so if you need more than one conversion, you are heading down a road to failure.

Comment: The seller does not answer. I have booted from a Linux Mint Live USB and it doesn't work through an USB to SAS to SATA enclosure, but other 2 rotational SAS disks of up to 2TB work there and through the LSI HBA.

Comment: When the seller doesn't rely that is typically a good indicating that you've been scammed.

Answer (score -3):

I think I found the answer:

**"sas" "ssd" cannot format**
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%22sas%22+%22ssd%22+cannot+format

**How to Reformat Sector Size 520b or 528b to 512b in Windows - 1139**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OLdRj-lCkE

Run the sg3 programs, format, and it should work if also Hard Disk Sentinel says that the disk has good health. Also install a Microsemi Adaptec SmartHBA 2100-4i4e and download its drivers from Microchip/Microsemi. **INSTALL a fan that is capable of cooling with 200 liters per minute, as the HBA card itself says.**

I just reformatted the SAS-3 12GBps SSD I initially wanted to fix, with these tools/instructions, and it went from being unable to be read or written, with cyclic redundancy check errors, I/O errors, bad block errors, to work even with SAS to USB enclosures under Windows 7.

After reformatting, I just ran with diskpart:

- list disk
- select disk X
- clean
- attribute disk clear readonly

Since it was read only after formatting, and then it was like any other normal disk.